# Show line only if within range (%)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The following script shows (historical) daily opens.

Problem:
This **works, if I hardcode the values (e.g. set rHi to 30k and rLo to 15k) but stops working, if I use the calculated values (rHi/rLo)**.

Goal:
I want to show only lines within a user defined price range (relative to todays opening price)

Approach:
To do so, Iet the user pick a number that I "convert" to a percentage (e.g. 10 becomes 10%. the range would be +/-10% of todays opening.)

Someone please help me unwire my brain on this?

---

Notes:

- The calculated values for rHi and rLo shows correct if plotted to the chart (e.g. as label)
- Using input.price is not an option since those handles on the chart
  are annoying and confuses most people.

---

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Show if within Range", overlay=true, max_lines_count=500)

// INPUT ------------------------------------------------------------------- //{

// tooltips
tt_i_range           = 'To show levels only within the deviation of todays opening price, specify a number to do the math.
                         \n\nThe value entered (whole number) defines the deviation in %'

// user choice
i_range              = input.float   (10,    'Percent',   tooltip=tt_i_range)
//}


// CORE FUNCTION ----------------------------------------------------------- //{

f_draw() =>
    var line _open  = na
    var _opens      = array.new_line()

    dOpen  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', open, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) // get opening price of the day
    
    rHi   = math.round((dOpen + i_range/100 * dOpen),1)                                     // Calculate range High based on user defined percantage and the developing day open price
    rLo   = math.round((dOpen - i_range/100 * dOpen),1)                                     // Calculate range Low based on user defined percantage and the developing day open price

    isBelowRangeTop     = dOpen <= rHi                                                      // PROBLEM: rHi value is ignored. If replaced with static number (e.g. 30000), it works
    isAboveRangeBottom  = dOpen >= rLo                                                      // PROBLEM: rLo value is ignored. If replaced with static number (e.g. 15000), it works
    inRange             = isBelowRangeTop and isAboveRangeBottom                            

    if inRange
        line.set_x2(_open, time)
        _open := line.new(time, dOpen, time, dOpen, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=color.green, style=line.style_solid, width=1)
        array.push(_opens, _open)
//}

// FUNCTION CALL ----------------------------------------------------------- //{
if timeframe.change('D')
    f_draw()
//}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating rHi as some percent above open and rLo as some percent below dOpen **at the last bar only**. And, compare the plotted line y with rHi and rLow and delete the line when its outside range. Like below

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Show if within Range", overlay=true, max_lines_count=500)

// INPUT ------------------------------------------------------------------- //{

// tooltips
tt_i_range           = 'To show levels only within the deviation of todays opening price, specify a number to do the math.
                         \n\nThe value entered (whole number) defines the deviation in %'

// user choice
i_range              = input.float   (10,    'Percent',   tooltip=tt_i_range)
//}
var line _open  = na
var linesarray=array.new<line>()
[bi,dOpen]  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', [bar_index,open], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) // get opening price of the day
           //             rHi   = math.round((dOpen + i_range/100 * dOpen),1)                                     // Calculate range High based on user defined percantage and the developing day open price
           //             rLo   = math.round((dOpen - i_range/100 * dOpen),1)      
           //             isBelowRangeTop     = high <= rHi                                                      
           //             isAboveRangeBottom  = low >= rLo                                                      
           //             inRange             = isBelowRangeTop and isAboveRangeBottom   

if bi>bi[1]
    _open := line.new(bar_index, dOpen, bar_index, dOpen,color=color.green, style=line.style_solid, width=1)
    array.push(linesarray,_open)
else
    line.set_x2(_open, bar_index)
var runonce=false
if barstate.islast
    rHi   = math.round((dOpen + i_range/100 * dOpen),1)
    rLo   = math.round((dOpen - i_range/100 * dOpen),1)
    if not runonce
        for i=0 to array.size(linesarray)-1
            liney=line.get_y1(array.get(linesarray,i))
            if liney<rLo or liney >rHi
                line.delete(array.get(linesarray,i))
        runonce=true
```

Comment: I get the problem, but am stucked with the solution provided since it also shows all "dOpen" ignoring the defined range in which they are allowed to show (+/- 10% of todays opening price). Sorry. Might be braindead.

Comment: dOpen is todays opening price so it will be within even +-0% of todays open

Comment: I am not sure we talk about the same. I appreciate the efforts, honestly but am stucked.

rHi and rLo are used to define the price range in which any historical dOpen may appear on the chart. Any historical dOpen outside that range is to be deleted and not printed.

Comment: ohk i understood that you want to compare historical day opens with only todays day open, will get back shortly

Comment: I have updated the answer to only take the todays open and delete any historical open line which is outside rHi and rLo

Comment: Man. I can't thank you enough for taking the efforts. I made a few adjustments to fit into my bigger script and its working now. 

Even though I got no idea why its not possible to only plot relevant lines, rather building an array with all of them first and then delete the overhead but it does the trick.